# Why wasn't the Flying Thunder God seal on Obito erased?

Tags: naruto

Tobirama said Obito might be using some kind of light and dark jutsu that turns all ninjutsu to nothing and only Senjutsu works on him. But I don't remember Tobirama getting into Sage Mode before placing the Flying Thunder God mark on Obito (well, it is not even told if he have a Sage Mode), but the mark was not erased in spite of being a ninjutsu. How can it be possible?

Comment: i'm also confused about it. but i think sealing jutsu thing works also.

Comment: He easily broke through two sealing jutsu's in the earlier chapters. That is the seal by hashirama and the powerful barrier of the Four Red Suns. Rather, the flying thunder god mark is not a Fūinjutsu. It is  a ninjutsu.

Comment: it's a seal. :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The marking itself is not ninjutsu, but rather just a type of seal. And Minato states that the marking never disappears from a marked target in Chapter 637.

EDIT:
Minato marked him with a seal prior to Obito becoming the Jinchuriki. When Obito transformed, the seal was removed. This is because each mark has a very specific destination. And when Obito transformed into a different being, that also counts as a different destination, which voids Minato's mark.

However, after Obito became the 10 tails Jinchuriki, Tobirama was able to place his own mark on Obito. This seal is Obito the Jinchuriki, and can't be removed unless Obito undergoes another transformation into something else.

[image]

Comment: but the mark made by Minato did disappear right?

Comment: Yes, but only because Obito turned into the 10 tails jinchuriki

Answer (score 0):

To negate a ninjutsu, Obito needs to use the black orbs either in defense or offense.

When Obito attacked Minato with the black orb, Obito's arm was not repaired back. And when Naruto+Sasuke attacked Obito, he used the black orb to absorb the combo attack.

So, o remove the  Flying Thunder God mark, he would need to use the black orbs on himslef, which is of a great risk. Maybe that is why he has not undone the technique.

Comment: If you read the manga, you must have noticed that he uses the black orbs on himself by making a hole in his palms for offence as well as defence. So the claim that using the black orbs on himself is risky does not hold good. He black orbs are indeed a part of his chakra(that is the Juubi's chakra), which of course he can use on his own body. And rather, to erase the combo from Naruto and Sasuke which hit him directly, obviously he used the black orbs on himself to erase it. And rather I think the black orbs act automatically, not according to the wish of Obito.

Comment: any substantial element to suggest that the black orbs are the part of jubi's chakra or that it acts automatically and not on the will of Obito?

Comment: Yes, when Obito got hit directly by the Naruto and Sasuke Combo, it was a direct hit and of course obito has no way of calling for the black orbs under such a situation. And rather as i earlier said, the black orbs cannot erase that attack completely without touching his body since the amaterasu is burning on his own body. And as i said, he shape manupulates and mixes the orbs with his own body for offence as well as defence. Hope you got what i meant.

Comment: Nope you are still unclear. how is it that you are determining that Obito has no way to call for the black orbs?